# parsin text out of .html page java

Tags: java, html

I want to parse this string out of a website and identif and store in a variable the color (lets say if its green assign value 0, or if other 1).

```
<tr><td class="mapbuttons" align=right>
<a href="http://www...."><font color=green>TEXT <font color=#ff8000>(2)</font>3/14</font></a>
```

I have found this demo code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WebSiteReader {
  public static void main(String args[]){
       String nextLine;
       URL url = null;
       URLConnection urlConn = null;
       InputStreamReader  inStream = null;
       BufferedReader buff = null;
       try{
          // Create the URL obect that points
          // at the default file index.html
          url  = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com" );
          urlConn = url.openConnection();
         inStream = new InputStreamReader( 
                           urlConn.getInputStream());
           buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);

       // get the values I want here

     } catch(MalformedURLException e){
       System.out.println("Please check the URL:" + 
                                           e.toString() );
     } catch(IOException  e1){
      System.out.println("Can't read  from the Internet: "+ 
                                          e1.toString() ); 
  }
 }
}
```

1) Is it correnct? i mean I jus thave to replace the comments with the codewhich does what I want, right?
2)Can you help me with the code cause I am new to java and how to "play" with texts?

Comment: If you want to play, use the String and Pattern classes. Those regexes will get big and ugly but they work. - that is just a play solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do the hard work (parsing the HTML for you).  It's really hard to parse HTML because a lot of the stuff that is out there is broken HTML.

Something akin to the below (not tested in the slightest should select the first font element and extract the value of the color attribute.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yahoo.com").get();
Element fontTag = doc.select("font").first();
string theColor = fontsTag.attr("color");
```

Comment: so what to replace from the above comment and place this? or where to insert it?

Comment: You should be able to remove most of the code above and just use the above.  `Jsoup` handles connecting to the website for you.

Comment: what if this code is not the first font in the html? or i want more than one fonts?